# How to understand git remote message?

Tags: git

I have create a new local repository (using git init, followed by adding and committing some files). Later I added a remote repository:

`$git remote add br /home/user/work/git/bare/`

I can see it through command git remote -v
Also git fetch br was successful

When I switch to this repo, it gives following message:

`$ git checkout br/master`

```
Note: checking out 'br/master'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at a155c68... Added Makefile.in`
```

I did not understand the above text? what is 'detached HEAD' state?

Just to add:

```
$ git branch

* (no branch)

  master

$
```

I am at no branch, how/why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-my-git-repo-enter-a-detached-head-state)

Answer (score 1):

You checked out a commit pointed to by a *remote branch* (you can list them using `git branch -r`). If it’s not pointed to by any local branch, it results in detached head. You should set `br/master` as upstream of your local `master`.

```
git checkout master
git branch -u br/master
```

You can then synchronize your local and remote `master` branch using `git push` and `git pull`.

Comment: Thanks @Melebius, it seems I need to learn more and more practice.